# What does pwn mean in server exploitation (in CTFs)?

Tags: ctf, pwntools

Pwn - I know that this is a category in CTFs in which you exploit a server to find the flag.

there is a library called pwntools, it's a CTF framework and exploit development library in python.

What I can't understand is why is it called "PWN" and is it an abbreviation?

pwn is also owning/dominating someone, but does this definition fit?

Thanks for helping ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is litereally just that. Owning the server. You're looking to far into it and forgetting the background in which this culture has risen.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of internet/hacking slang, it indeed means that your server (or data or anything else) has been taken over control, that you "lost the game".

I think this is an abbreviation from "pawned", from the verb "to pawn", used in games, though I can't find a reliable and authoritative source for it (same as current [wiktionary word article is stating](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pwn#English)).

I feel like it has roots in the chess game (where you used pieces called "pawns").

It sounds like "owned" and "punched". It might also be some invented word.